# "zpool create" hangs indefinitely

Tags: solaris, zfs

I have a Solaris 11.1 machine which has some disks attached to it via an expander (LSISAS2X36) through an LSI 1068 controller. The setup used to work quite decently, but as I have added another batch of disks, I see some strange effects:

- `format` hangs after selecting a disk (any disk) if I do not specify `NOINUSE_CHECK=1`
- I cannot create new pools, a simple `zpool create test c10d20t0` will hang - seemingly due to the same reason as `format` does. The NOINUSE_CHECK variable seems to have no effect, although [old news archives](http://osdir.com/ml/os.solaris.opensolaris.zfs/2006-09/msg00576.html) seem to suggest that it seemed to help for previous releases of Solaris.

I already tried running `devfsadm -Cv` to clean up dev entries for non-present devices, but to no avail. I also figured that invalid partition information on one of the newly added disks might cause the *"in use"* check to hang and ran the `fdisk` menu for all of the added disks to create a 100% Solaris partition, but this did not help things either.

A `truss zpool create test c10t20d0` reveals a lot of reading links off `/dev/rdsk/` and stops with these lines:

```
readlink("/dev/zvol/rdsk/rpool/dump", "../../../..//devices/pseudo/zfs@0:1,raw", 1023) = 39
lstat("/dev", 0xF8D35310)                       = 0
lstat("/dev/zvol", 0xF8D35310)                  = 0
lstat("/dev/zvol/rdsk", 0xF8D35310)             = 0
lstat("/dev/zvol/rdsk/rpool", 0xF8D35310)       = 0
lstat("/dev/zvol/rdsk/rpool/swap", 0xF8D35310)  = 0
readlink("/dev/zvol/rdsk/rpool/swap", "../../../..//devices/pseudo/zfs@0:2,raw", 1023) = 39
open("/devices/pseudo/devinfo@0:devinfo", O_RDONLY) = 7
ioctl(7, DINFOIDENT, 0x00000000)                = 57311
ioctl(7, 0x10DF00, 0xF8D36F10)                  = 380014
ioctl(7, DINFOUSRLD, 0x08D62000)                = 380928
close(7)                                        = 0
close(6)                                        = 0
munmap(0xF5FE1000, 4096)                        = 0
munmap(0xF5FD2000, 20480)                       = 0
munmap(0xF5FC7000, 24576)                       = 0
munmap(0xF6014000, 110592)                      = 0
munmap(0xF6030000, 40)                          = 0
close(5)                                        = 0
stat64("/opt/VRTSvxvm/lib/libsysevent.so.1", 0xF8D36910) Err#2 ENOENT
stat64("/lib/libsysevent.so.1", 0xF8D36910)     = 0
resolvepath("/lib/libsysevent.so.1", "/lib/libsysevent.so.1", 1023) = 21
open("/lib/libsysevent.so.1", O_RDONLY)         = 5
mmapobj(5, MMOBJ_INTERPRET, 0xF6040B78, 0xF8D3697C, 0x00000000) = 0
close(5)                                        = 0
mmap(0x00000000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON, -1, 0) = 0xF5FE0000
memcntl(0xF6020000, 11280, MC_ADVISE, MADV_WILLNEED, 0, 0) = 0
getuid()                                        = 0 [0]
statvfs("/system/volatile", 0xF8D369B0)         = 0
stat("/system/volatile/sysevent_channels", 0xF8D36A50) = 0
mkdir("/system/volatile/sysevent_channels/syseventd_channel", 0755) Err#17 EEXIST
stat("/system/volatile/sysevent_channels/syseventd_channel", 0xF8D368F0) = 0
getuid()                                        = 0 [0]
modctl(MODEVENTS, 0x00000006, 0x08D560EB, 0x00000000, 0xF8D36880) = 0
modctl(MODEVENTS, 0x00000006, 0x08D560EB, 0x00000000, 0xF8D36A40) = 0
unlink("/system/volatile/sysevent_channels/syseventd_channel/59") Err#2 ENOENT
open("/system/volatile/sysevent_channels/syseventd_channel/59", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0600) = 5
door_create(0xF6024174, 0x08D56088, DOOR_REFUSE_DESC|DOOR_NO_CANCEL) = 6
getpid()                                        = 22082 [22081]
priocntlsys(1, 0xF8D365B0, 3, 0xF8D366A0, 0)    = 22082
priocntlsys(1, 0xF8D36540, 1, 0xF8D36600, 0)    = 4
priocntlsys(1, 0xF8D36500, 0, 0xF6575FB8, 0)    = 4
mmap(0x00000000, 131072, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON, -1, 0) = 0xF5FBF000
mmap(0x00000000, 65536, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON, -1, 0) = 0xF5FA0000
sigaction(SIGCANCEL, 0xF8D366C0, 0x00000000)    = 0
sysconfig(_CONFIG_STACK_PROT)                   = 3
mmap(0x00000000, 1040384, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_NORESERVE|MAP_ANON, -1, 0) = 0xF5EA1000
mmap(0x00010000, 65536, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANON|MAP_ALIGN, -1, 0) = 0xF5E90000
getcontext(0xF8D36510)
uucopy(0xF8D364D0, 0xF5F9EFEC, 20)              = 0
lwp_create(0xF8D36760, LWP_DETACHED|LWP_SUSPENDED, 0xF8D3675C) = 2
/1:     lwp_continue(2)                                 = 0
/2:     lwp_create()    (returning as new lwp ...)      = 0
/1:     yield()                                         = 0
/2:     setustack(0xF5E902A0)
/2:     schedctl()                                      = 0xF623B040
/1:     umount2("/system/volatile/sysevent_channels/syseventd_channel/59", 0x00000000) Err#22 EINVAL
/1:     ioctl(6, I_CANPUT, 0x00000000)                  Err#89 ENOSYS
/1:     door_info(6, 0xF8D36640)                        = 0
/1:     mount(0, "/system/volatile/sysevent_channels/syseventd_channel/59", MS_DATA|MS_NOMNTTAB, "namefs", 0xF8D3663C, 4, 0x00000000, 0) = 0
/1:     close(5)                                        = 0
/1:     open("/system/volatile/sysevent_channels/syseventd_channel/reg_door", O_RDONLY) = 5
/2:     door_return(0x00000000, 0, 0x00000000, 0xF5F9EE00, 1007360) (sleeping...)
/1:     door_call(5, 0xF8D369F0)        (sleeping...)
^C/1:       Received signal #2, SIGINT, in door_call() [default]
```

a `truss  format c10t20d0` looks pretty much the same towards the end.

Anything else I could do to narrow down the possible causes or just try and see if it would work?

Comment: If format hangs then I would suspect some problems with the disks itself or with the controller. I had a similar problem when one of my local disks died and the whole SCSI bus hung. Check out if the disks are visible with `cfgadm -la`

Comment: Forgot to mention... anything suspicious in `/var/adm/messages`?

Comment: @b13n1u Disks in general are visible with `cfgadm -la`, the output also seems to contain a reference to a pulled disk `c10::sd21` - `iostat -xdmn` also is still listing it (although iostat is meant to keep removed disk's stats as I understand). The available disks are also working as expected so far - an existing zpool is running in ONLINE state, the newly attached disks are readable. No relevant entries can be found in the logs and/or on the console.

Comment: I just noticed I cannot `unconfigure` the pulled disk via `cfgadm` - it returns `cfgadm: Hardware specific failure: failed to unconfigure SCSI device: I/O error`. I wonder how I could just kick it from my configuration without rebooting the system.

Comment: Stupid guess, have you tried to force the unconfigure `cfgadm -f -c unconfigure`

Comment: @b13n1u yes, same result. I am going to try to get a downtime service window for this machine and see if rebooting helps matters (it should remove sd21 at least). In the meantime, I wonder if removing all symlink references to the device would do the trick. At least removing c10t19d0* from /dev/dsk and /dev/rdsk did not. Probably there is more somewhere.

Comment: Probably you will also need to remove the major minor entries and clean it up in pat_to_inst. But it looks to be the best way to destroy your system :) So I would suggest to go for a reboot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the system did not handle a pulled disk very well. Although most of it seemed to work correctly, the `format` and `zpool create` commands hung even after the missing disk has been re-inserted.

Rebooting the system helped matters - a fast reboot was sufficient.